# How to generate unique hash code for a string with Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, hashcode

I'd like to generate hash code for a string using Cypher only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, definitely use one of the [APOC hash functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/), but you could create your own hash function.

For example, here's a hacky [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) string hash implementation in `Cypher`.

```
WITH " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~" as chars
RETURN reduce(acc=5381, c  in split("Gimme a String Hash Please!","") | (acc*33 + size(split(chars,c)[0]))%toInteger(2^32))
```

> `337735339` is returned for this string.